# calculating sales, refund and breakages from SQL Server Tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, c#, t-sql

I have 4 tables namely Products, SalesLog, Breakages, SalesReturn.

**Products Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
[ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[pName] [nvarchar](30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[pSize] [int] NULL,
[pPrice] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[pPackQty] [int] NULL,
[pGroup] [int] NULL,
[pCode] [int] NULL,
[OpenStock] [int] NULL,
[CloseStock] [int] NULL,
[YrlyOpenStock] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**SalesLog Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesLog](
[SalesID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MemoNo] [int] NULL,
[ProductCode] [int] NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NULL,
[Price] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[pGroup] [int] NULL,
[pName] [nvarchar](30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[pSize] [int] NULL,
[BillDate] [nchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SalesLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SalesID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**SalesReturn Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesReturn](
[srID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProductCode] [int] NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NULL,
[pGroup] [int] NULL,
[MemoNo] [int] NULL,
[SalesmanID] [int] NULL,
[Price] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[JobShift] [int] NULL,
[BillDate] [nchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[AddedOn] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SalesReturn] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[srID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Breakages Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Breakages](
[breakId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MemoNo] [int] NULL,
[SalesmanID] [int] NULL,
[ProductCode] [int] NULL,
[pName] [nvarchar](30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NULL,
[Price] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[pGroup] [int] NULL,
[JobShift] [int] NULL,
[BillDate] [nchar](10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[AddedOn] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Breakages_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[breakId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have to generate a single report to show SalesLOg, SalesReturn and Breakages of particular date (according to BillDate column of SalesLog, Breakages and SalesReturn) in following pattern.

**Wanted Output**

```
Code      ItemName     Price     SalesQty     BreakagesQty    SalesReturnQty
 1           A          $10         50              2               2
 1           A          $12         150             1               10
 15          X          $5          56              0               2
 20          Z          $8          121             0               0
```

**Reduced output column for the sake of reading**

as you can see that Product "A" has been listed twice because of price change of that product. to achieve this i have written a query:

```
SELECT     SalesLog.pName, SalesLog.ProductCode, MIN(ItemGroup.gName) AS GroupName, 
           SalesLog.Price, SUM    (SalesLog.Quantity) AS SalesQty, 
           SUM(SalesLog.Quantity * SalesLog.Price) AS SalesValue, 
     ISNULL ((SELECT     SUM(Quantity) AS Expr1 FROM Breakages
        WHERE (ProductCode = SalesLog.ProductCode) AND (Price = SalesLog.Price) AND 
          (BillDate = '07/01/2010') AND (pGroup <> 15) AND (pGroup <> 16)), 0) AS BreakQty, 
     ISNULL ((SELECT     SUM(Quantity * Price) AS Expr1
 FROM         Breakages
        WHERE     (ProductCode = SalesLog.ProductCode) AND (Price = SalesLog.Price) AND 
          (BillDate = '07/01/2010') AND (pGroup <> 15) AND (pGroup <> 16)), 0) AS BreakValue, 
     ISNULL ((SELECT     SUM(Quantity) AS Expr1
 FROM         SalesReturn
       WHERE     (ProductCode = SalesLog.ProductCode) AND (Price = SalesLog.Price) AND 
          (BillDate = '07/01/2010') AND (pGroup <> 15) AND (pGroup <> 16)), 0) AS ReturnQty, 
     ISNULL ((SELECT     SUM(Quantity * Price) AS Expr1
 FROM         SalesReturn
       WHERE     (ProductCode = SalesLog.ProductCode) AND (Price = SalesLog.Price) AND 
          (BillDate = '07/01/2010') AND (pGroup <> 15) AND (pGroup <> 16)), 0) AS ReturnValue, 
     ISNULL ((SELECT     SUM(Quantity) AS Expr1
 FROM         SalesLog
       WHERE     (ProductCode = Products.pCode)), 0) AS CummSales
 FROM         SalesLog 
          INNER JOIN
              ItemGroup ON ItemGroup.gCode = SalesLog.pGroup AND SalesLog.pGroup = ItemGroup.gCode 
          INNER JOIN
              Products ON Products.pCode = SalesLog.ProductCode
       WHERE  (SalesLog.BillDate = '07/01/2010') AND (SalesLog.pGroup <> 15) AND 
              (SalesLog.pGroup <> 16)
GROUP BY SalesLog.pName, SalesLog.ProductCode, SalesLog.Price, Products.pCode, Products.pPrice
ORDER BY SalesLog.ProductCode, SalesLog.pName
```

My problem with this query is, It is unable to show entries of items where there is no sales but there is sales return. this condition is give by my client. Can you help me on this. any t-sql query or logic to implement this condition will help...

thank you for bearing me.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  MIN(Products.pName) AS pName,
        Products.pCode AS ProductCode,
        MIN(Products.pGroup) AS GroupName, 
        Sales_Trans.Price,
        SUM(Sales_Trans.Sales_Qty) AS SalesQty, 
        SUM(Sales_Trans.Sales_Value) AS SalesValue, 
        SUM(Sales_Trans.Break_Qty) AS BreakQty, 
        SUM(Sales_Trans.Break_Value) AS BreakValue, 
        SUM(Sales_Trans.Return_Qty) AS ReturnQty, 
        SUM(Sales_Trans.Return_Value) AS ReturnValue, 
FROM Products
JOIN        
(SELECT ProductCode, Price, Quantity Sales_Qty, Price * Quantity Sales_Value, 0 Break_Qty, 0 Break_Value, 0 Return_Qty, 0 Return_Value FROM SalesLog
 WHERE  (BillDate = '07/01/2010') AND (pGroup <> 15) AND (pGroup <> 16)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ProductCode, Price, 0 Sales_Qty, 0 Sales_Value, 0 Break_Qty, 0 Break_Value, Quantity Return_Qty, Price * Quantity Return_Value FROM SalesReturn
 WHERE  (BillDate = '07/01/2010') AND (pGroup <> 15) AND (pGroup <> 16)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ProductCode, Price, 0 Sales_Qty, 0 Sales_Value, Quantity Break_Qty, Price * Quantity Break_Value, 0 Return_Qty, 0 Return_Value FROM Breakages
 WHERE  (BillDate = '07/01/2010') AND (pGroup <> 15) AND (pGroup <> 16)
) Sales_Trans
ON (Products.pCode = Sales_Trans.ProductCode) and (Products.pPrice = Sales_Trans.Price)
GROUP BY Products.pCode, Sales_Trans.Price
ORDER BY 2,1
```

(This assumes a full history of price changes is stored in the Products table - if only the latest prices are stored on Products, then the Products.pPrice = Sales_Trans.Price join condition will need to be removed.)

Comment: thank you @Mark Bannister, I can't tell how you helped me. This query is doing what I wanted. Thanks alot..........................................