# how to show sales summary in rdlc from four sql table using sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, rdlc

I am having bad times to generate a rdlc report to show report in predefined format given by my client.

**Client given format**
[image: Output format]

As you can notice RED background is my problem area, Item "A" price has been changed thrice. And accordingly their sales, breakages and refund quantity is shown. I have 4 tables Products, SalesLog, Breakages, SalesReturn. Product table consists latest(current) price of an item but SalesLog, Breakages and SalesReturn tables consists price at the time of Sales, Breakages and Sales Return. I have written queries for SalesLog, Breakges and SalesReturn which shows rows according to ProductCode, Price and Quantity. But i don't understand how I can merge their (4 tables output) output to show below result.

**Query for SalesLog**

```
SELECT  [Products].pCode AS Code,
    [Products].pName AS Item,
    SalesLog.[Price] AS Price ,
    COUNT(*)AS Quantity ,
    SUM(SalesLog.[Price]) AS Total
FROM    SalesLog
    INNER JOIN [Products] ON [Products].pCode = SalesLog.ProductCode
WHERE   BillDate = '07/01/2010'
GROUP BY [Products].pCode,[Products].pName ,
    SalesLog.[Price]
```

**Query for Breakages**

```
SELECT  [Products].pCode AS Code,
    [Products].pName AS Item,
    Breakages.[Price] AS Price ,
    COUNT(*)AS Quantity ,
    SUM(Breakages.[Price]) AS Total
FROM    Breakages
    INNER JOIN [Products] ON [Products].pCode = Breakages.ProductCode
WHERE   BillDate = '07/01/2010'
GROUP BY [Products].pCode,[Products].pName ,
    Breakages.[Price]
```

**Query for SalesReturn**

```
SELECT  [Products].pCode AS Code,
    [Products].pName AS Item,
    Breakages.[Price] AS Price ,
    COUNT(*)AS Quantity ,
    SUM(Breakages.[Price]) AS Total
FROM    Breakages
    INNER JOIN [Products] ON [Products].pCode = Breakages.ProductCode
WHERE   BillDate = '07/01/2010'
GROUP BY [Products].pCode,[Products].pName ,
    Breakages.[Price]
```

**Product Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pName] [nvarchar](30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [pSize] [int] NULL,
    [pPrice] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [pPackQty] [int] NULL,
    [pGroup] [int] NULL,
    [pCode] [int] NULL,
    [OpenStock] [int] NULL,
    [CloseStock] [int] NULL,
    [YrlyOpenStock] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(    
    [ProductId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Can anyone help me, or suggest any trick to accomplish this.

thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just off the top of my head from looking at your data.  I think I'd just pull out a unique list of "Code", "Item", "Price" and then use this unique list to LEFT JOIN against each one of your queries (Sales, Breakage, Return).  You can use a coalesce to default the values to 0 if they are null, and you can use a final where clause to drop-out any records that have zero for all three results (unless you want to show there was nothing done at a given price).

Answer (score 2):

Would something along the following lines be of any use?
(Give or take a square bracket or two as I'm no great whizz on SQL Server).

```
SELECT [Products].pCode AS Code,
       [Products].pName AS Item,
       SLO.[Price]      AS Price,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM SalesLog SL
           WHERE SL.ProductCode = SLO.ProductCode AND
                 SL.Billdate    = SLO.BillDate) AS SalesQty,
       (SELECT SUM(SL.Price)
           FROM SalesLog SL
           WHERE SL.ProductCode = SLO.ProductCode AND
                 SL.Billdate    = SLO.BillDate) AS SalesValue,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Breakages
            WHERE Breakages.ProductCode = SLO.ProductCode AND
                  Breakages.BillDate    = SLO.BillDate) AS BreakageQty,
       ...etc...

FROM SalesLog SLO INNER JOIN [Products] ON [Products].pCode = SLO.ProductCode
    WHERE BillDate = '07/01/2010'
    GROUP BY [Products].pCode,
             [Products].pName ,
             SLO.[Price]
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally a question which I asked on ServerFault.co,m which moved to StackOverFlow.com by their Admin has got an answer which I think is easy to get (for me at least). Please don't mind those guys who helped me. this query is doing what i wanted.

Thanks to all for their support (especially **STACKOVERFLOW.COM**)

[Click here to view answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278583/calculating-sales-refund-and-breakages-from-sql-server-tables/3282601#3282601)